# Homestead/Vagrant virtual server error: default: stdin: is not a TTY

Tags: vagrant

- Mac OS X 10.10.1
- Vagrant 1.7.2
- Laravel Homestead 4.2

When attempting the command `vagrant up` the server appears to boot, but then seems to fail, returning to the command prompt. Boot up seems to be going fine, then I get the following errors/warnings in the log:

```
default: Running: inline script
==> default: stdin: is not a tty
```

This pattern occurs several times and then the boot seems to fail.

Note however that activity monitor does show a some Vbox entries.

Answer (score 0):

You should expect to return to your command prompt when running `vagrant up`, which just starts the VM (and provisions it if necessary). If you want to be logged onto the VM also, you should run `vagrant up && vagrant ssh`.

As far as the "not a tty" error, it's a red herring. It's an issue between Vagrant and some Linux variants including Ubuntu, but doesn't actually hurt anything. You can fix it if it's bothering you; I've posted some [instructions and an explanation](http://foo-o-rama.com/vagrant--stdin-is-not-a-tty--fix.html).